# Intel c++ - optimizer messages

Tags: c, gcc, clang, intel

I wonder if it's possible to make Intel C++ compiler (or other compilers such as gcc or clang) display some messages from optimizer. I would like to know what exactly optimizer did with my code. By default compiler prints only very basic things like unused variable. very simple example - I want to know that expression;

```
float x =  1.0f/2;
```

will be evaluated into:

```
float x = 0.5f;
```

and there will be no division in code (I know that in this case it's always true, but this is just an example). More advanced example could be loop unroll or operations reorder.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u try gcc option **-S** when compiling. You should get **.s** file  containing optimized assembly code for ur c code..

Comment: Try with `-Wremarks` too. It's show a lot of warnings that `-Wall -Wextra` combination don't.

Comment: @Jack: which versions of GCC accepts `-Wremarks`? It seems Intel compiler specific!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It's an intel compiler's flag really. That's compiler that he's using,isn't? In fact,I not ever see gcc tag when I did first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For icc and icpc, you can use the `-opt-report -opt-report-level max` set of flags.

You can also specify an opt-report file.  See [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/e/f/4/5/2/6747-vtune_compiler_advice.pdf) for more details

Comment: Excellent, missed this doc.

Answer (score 1):

An optimizing compiler (like GCC, when asked to optimize with `-O1` or `-O2` etc...) is essentially transforming internal representations of your source code.

If you want to see some of the internal GCC representations, you could pass `-fdump-tree-all` to GCC. Beware, you'll get hundreds of dump files.

You could also use the [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id): MELT is a domain specific language (and plugin implementation) to extend GCC, and it has a probe mode to interactively show some of the internal (notably Gimple) representations.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization you describe at the top of the post is (somewhat strangely) part of icc -fno-prec-div (which is a default which you might be overriding).